# $\int^x_2 (\log u)^{-2} du\ll x(\log x)^{-2}$

Tags: analysis

I came across this estimation in a book:

$$
\int^x_2 (\log u)^{-2} du \ll x(\log x)^{-2}.
$$

I tried to prove it by first integrating by parts:

$$
\int^x_2 (\log u)^{-2} du = x(\log x)^{-2}-2(\log 2)^{-2} + 2\int^x_2 (\log u)^{-3} du,
$$

but was then stuck. Could someone show me how to establish the estimation?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of $\ll$?

Comment: By $f\ll g$ the book meant that there is a constant $C>0$ such that $f(x)\le C g(x)$, in some domain of $x$. Here, I actually wanted for all $x\ge2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By L'Hospital's rule
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{\int_2^x {\frac{{du}}{{\log ^2 u}}} }}{{\frac{x}{{\log ^2 x}}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{{\frac{1}{{\log ^2 x}}}}{{\frac{1}{{\log ^2 x}} - \frac{2}{{\log ^3 x}}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{{1 - \frac{2}{{\log x}}}} = 1.
$$
Thus we in fact have
$$
\int_2^x {\frac{{du}}{{\log ^2 u}}}  \sim \frac{x}{{\log ^2 x}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But actually I wanted for all $x\ge2$.

Comment: @Tapioka That is a consequence of this.

Comment: @ Gary: At first glance, it seemed that only for sufficiently large $x$ was proved.

Comment: The ratio tends to $1$. Thus there is an $X>2$ so that for $x>X$ the ratio is at most $2$, say. For $2\leq x\leq X$, the ratio has a maximum value $K$ since it is a continuous function. Thus, the ratio is at most $\max(2,K)$ for all $x\geq 2$.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation!

Comment: @Tapioka If you appreciate an answer then you should upvote it and give it the $\color{green}{\checkmark}$